# Can a set have a subset which doesn't exist?

Tags: set-theory

Is it possible in **ZF** that given some set $S$, we can informally "describe" a set $P$ such that $P \subseteq S$, and $P$ does not exist (or we can not prove within **ZF** that P exists)?

In other words is it possible that for some set $S$, there is a set $P$ which doesn't exist, but if it existed, it would be a subset of $S$? (Or the existence of $P$ is not decidable.)

Comment: Are you asking if existence proofs are legitimate?

Comment: Sure, anything using AC will generally fit this description.

Comment: So he was then.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: It seems to me that when you apply **AC** on a set $S$, you get a set $P$ such that $P \subseteq \bigcup S$, not $P \subseteq S$ as was required.

Comment: You get a set and it lives as a subset of a specified set. Sure, not the set you "started" with, but that just means you needed to start a different place.

Comment: @Tobias: I'm not quite sure what the axiom of choice has to do with this.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, it is something that tends to provide the existence of certain subsets which might not exist in ZF alone.

Comment: @Tobias: But it misses the entire point here. Provability, and the axiom of choice amongst other axioms, is syntactic and existence is semantic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That is getting beyond the sort of thing I know anything about (and as far as I can tell, beyond the level the OP was looking for).

Comment: @Tobias: It's very easy to ask questions whose answers is complicated. An unfortunate side effect of life.

Comment: @Graduate: Some response on the answer I wrote you would be nice. Have you read it, have you understood it, are you still thinking about it, something?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I didn't read your answer at that moment, but I put it aside to read it later (make a bookmark). So I would have read it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you believe there is a single true universe of sets, then the answer is no. If something is a subset, then it exists and therefore in that true universe of sets.

If you want to be a bit more mathematical, and less dogmatic, then you can observe that existence is a property relative to a given model. For example, in the group $\Bbb Z$ there are no elements of order $2$, whereas in the group $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ there exists an element of order $2$.

If we assume that our background theory is $\sf ZFC$, then given a model of set theory it might be "closed under subsets" from the point of view of the background universe, for example if the model happens to be $V_\kappa$ for some inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$. In that case, every subset of an element of the model "exists" in that model.

But it might be the case that the model we talk about is not closed under subsets from the point of view of the universe. For example, if the model is countable it can only have countably many subsets of $\omega$, but we know that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ subsets in the background universe. Therefore the majority of the subsets of $\omega$ are not part of that model, and so they do not exist there. The generic Cohen real in William's answer is a typical example of such set.

Other typical examples would be in the case the model $M$ is not even well-founded. In that case we can consider the set $A=\{x\in\mathrm{Ord}^M\mid x\text{ is truly well-founded}\}$, then this is an initial segment of the ordinals of $M$ (and one can easily show that it has to be infinite too), and this set is not in the model $M$. But since $M$ is not well-founded there is some ordinal $u$ of $M$ which is larger than all the ordinals in $A$. It is true that $A$ is not necessarily a subset of $u$ in the sense of the background universe, but for every $x\in A$, $M\models x\in u$. So it is a subset in the sense of $M$, even though it "doesn't exist".

But unless you specify a model, it's hard to talk about existence and non-existence of subsets. In particular because in some cases it is possible to have a model which is closed under taking subsets, so there is no absolute answer here (unless you believe that $\sf ZFC$ outright disproves large cardinals in which case you might argue that any model of $\sf ZFC$ is not of the form $V_\kappa$, and therefore in every model of $\sf ZFC$ there are some subsets of an element of the model which are not in the model itself).

Comment: I don't have enough background to fully understand the answer. For example, I have not studied cardinals and ordinals. But I accept your answer as the one that provides more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague, so you should decide for yourself if the following example fits what are looking for:

So suppose $M$ is a model of $\text{ZFC}$. Let $\mathbb{C}$ denote Cohen forcing and $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be $\mathbb{C}$-generic over $M$. In the larger models $M[G]$, $G$ produces a subset $P_G$ of the natural numbers which is not a set in $M$.

So in the larger universe $M[G]$, the natural numbers has $P_G$ as a subset; however, if you return to the smaller universe $M$, $P_G$ does not exist.